# How can I put a character to a line in Bash

Tags: bash

I have  file which has lines like that:

> Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013 GBPCAD 158.000000

I want to add ';' to specific columns and convert it to

> Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013;GBPCAD;158.000000

How can I do that?

Comment: Where does this text come from? Because it might be easier to format it beforehand.

Comment: i generate it by 'cut'ting from a longer line.

Comment: Is it always at the same column? Even if your date is `Mon Dec 9 14:03:45 2013`? Or does it show up as `Mon Dec 09 14:03:45 2013`?

Comment: So is it always after a YYYY (year) that you have to print the first semicolon?

Comment: yes, the date format is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Sed might be of help.

```
sed -e 's/\ \([^ ]*\)\ \([^ ]*\)$/;\1;\2/g' file
```

Test

```
$ sed -e 's/\ \([^ ]*\)\ \([^ ]*\)$/;\1;\2/g' <<< 'Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013 GBPCAD 158.000000'
Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013;GBPCAD;158.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '{$(NF-2)=$(NF-2)";"$(NF-1)";"$NF;NF=NF-2};{print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

**sed**

```
sed -r 's/ (\w{5,}) /;\1;/' file

kent$   echo "Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013 GBPCAD 158.000000"|sed -r 's/ (\w{5,}) /;\1;/'                                  
Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013;GBPCAD;158.000000
```

or **awk**

```
awk '{s=";"$(NF-1)";"$NF;NF-=2}$0=$0 s' file

kent$   echo "Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013 GBPCAD 158.000000"|awk '{s=";"$(NF-1)";"$NF;NF-=2}$0=$0 s'
Tue Dec 10 14:03:45 2013;GBPCAD;158.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

bash:

```
while read -a words; do
    printf "%s;%s;%s\n" "${words[*]:0:5}" "${words[5]}" "${words[6]}"
done < filename
```